# How to implement general Filter method in Go

Tags: go

as a newbee in golang, i want to know how to implement a general method like Filter/Map.

Basically what I want to do is,

```
Filter(data []T, func (item T) {
    return item.xxx
})
```

From what i know is, golang doesn't support generic(maybe wrong), and there is the [generic proposal here](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/15292-generics.md).

And of course, i really don't want to copy and paste to support different struct.

So what is the golang way to do it?

Comment: The golang way to do it to just use for loops. If you really want to do it, use this https://github.com/robpike/filter

Comment: You need to use `interface{}` to achieve something like parametric polymorphism.   When you need aspects of type to implement your "polymorphic" functions, you type-convert to an interface of some specific signature.  Although you can play games with the `reflect` package to make up for it, but you'll never be able to use the type system to type your `Filter` function accurately.

Comment: (why the downvote? this is a valid question...)

Comment: @BadZen Thx for your solution, it looks more intuitive, is there an example package that I can check with? I mean the parametric polymorphism part.